# parameter in sql query :SSRS

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, parameters

I am using `oracleclient` provider.  I was wondering how do I use a parameter in the query.

```
select * from table A where A.a in ( parameter).
```

The parameter should be a `multivalue` parameter.

how do I create a data set?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Add the parameter to the report and make sure to check it off as multi-valued. Then in the data tab and go in and edit the query click the "..." button to edit the dataset. Under the parameters tab create a mapping parameter so it looks something like this (obviously you will have different names for your parameters):

```
@ids | =Parameters!ContractorIDS.Value
```

Then in the query tab use the coorelated sub-query like your example above. I have done this many times with SQL server and there is no reason it should not work with Oracle since SSRS is going to build an ANSI compliant SQL statement which it will pass to Oracle.

```
where A.myfield in (@ids)
```

Comment: This is fine for SQL Server but not for Oracle. You should have tested this against Oracle before you provided it as an answer. I agree there's no reason it shouldn't work, but I can tell you from experience that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a variable in list in oracle directly.  You can however, break apart a comma seperated list into rows that can be used in your subquery.  The string txt can be replaced by any number of values seperated by a comma.

```
   select * from a where a.a in ( 
       SELECT regexp_substr(txt,'[^,]+',1,level)
         FROM (SELECT 'hello,world,hi,there' txt  -- replace with parameter
                 FROM DUAL)
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE (txt, '[^,]'))+1
   )
```

The query works by first counting the number of commas that are in the text string.  It does this by using a reqular expression to remove all non commas and then counts the length of the remainder.

It then uses an Oracle "trick" to return that number + 1 number of rows from the dual table.  It then uses the regexp_substr function to pull out each occurence.

Comment: I don't believe the variable is not in the list by the time it hits Oracle. SSRS takes this value and breaks it up into static inline query text, so it should still work as long as Oracle supports the "IN" query operator.

Comment: Edit:
I don't believe the variable is in the list by the time it hits Oracle. SSRS takes this value and breaks it up into static inline query text, so it should still work as long as Oracle supports the "IN" query operator.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in SSRS with an Oracle OLEDB connection you need to use the colon, not the @ symbol e.g. :parameter not @parameter but then you aren't able to do this as a multi-valued parameter, it only accepts single values. Worse, if you are using an ODBC connection you have to use the question mark by itself e.g. ? not @parameter and then the ordering of parameters becomes important, and they also cannot be multi-valued. The only ways you are left with is using an expression to construct a query (join() function for the param) or calling a stored proc.

The stored proc option is best because the SSRS can handle the parameters for stored procs to both SQL Server and Oracle very cleanly, but if that is not an option you can use this expression:

```
="select column1, column2, a from table A where A.a in (" + Join(Parameters!parameter.Value,", ") + ")"
```

Or if the parameter values are strings which need apostrophes around them:

```
="select column1, column2, a from table A where A.a in ('" + Join(Parameters!parameter.Value,"', '") + "')"
```

When you right-click on the dataset, you can select "dataset properties" and then use the fx button to edit the query as an expression, rather than using the query designer which won't let you edit it as an expression.

This expression method is limited to a maximum limit of about 1000 values but if you have that many this is the wrong way to do it anyway, you'd rather join to a table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a parameter in such a situation.
(Unless oracle and the language you're using supports array-type parameters ? )

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in oracle are defined as ":parametername", so in your query you should use something like:

```
select * from table A where value in (:parametername)
```

Add the parameter to the paramaters folders in the report and mark the checkbox "Allow multiple values".

Answer (score 0):

As Victor Grimaldo mentioned… below worked for me very fine. As soon as I use the `:parameter` in my SQL query in SSRS dataset1.. it asked me to enter the values for these parameters, for which I choose already created SSRS parameters.

`SELECT * FROM table a WHERE VALUE IN (**:parametername**)`

Thanks Victor.